# `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::ATM (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I've been creating an ATM for a couple days now and have recently come across this error when trying to make the class run, I understand that `<top (required)>'` means that something there's something going on with the top of the file, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with this, can someone please explain to me what the problem is here, and how I should go about fixing it?

main.rb source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

################
#ATM Rewrite 
#                                
#Creator Lost Bam      
#                        
#11/19/15                
##################

require_relative 'initialize.rb'
require_relative 'checking.rb'
require_relative 'savings.rb'
require_relative 'transfer.rb'
require_relative 'loan.rb'
require_relative './ready/exit.rb'#if you're gonna run the file take the './ready' off of this one`
require_relative './ready/redirect.rb'# and this one

class ATM
    attr_accessor :name, :checking_account, :savings_account, :pin_number, :transfer, :loan
        def initialize( name, checking_account, savings_account, pin_number )
            @name = name
            @checking_account = checking_account
            @savings_account = savings_account
            @pin_number = pin_number
        end
    end

    def pin #add regex =~ /^\d{4}/ to compare against input of user for a 4 digit combination
        x = 3
        while (x > 0) do
            puts "Enter PIN(#{x} attempts left):"
            pin_num = gets.chomp
            case pin_num.to_i
            when @pin_number
                menu
            else
                puts "Invalid PIN"
                x -= 1
                bad_pin if x == 0
            end
        end
    end

    def menu 
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >Welcome #{name} thank you for choosing Bank of Bam.
            >You may choose from the list below of what you would like to do
            >For checking inquiries press '1'
            >For savings account information press '2'
            >To transfer funds press '3'
            >To either apply for a loan, or get information on a loan press '4'
            >To exit the system press '5'
            >
        END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            checking_information
        when 2
            savings_information
        when 3
            transfer_funds
        when 4
            loan_info
        when 5
            exit_screen
        else
            puts "Error Invalid option please try again"
            menu
        end
    end

    def bad_pin
        abort('Exiting system, all attempts failed...')
        exit
    end
```

initialize.rb source( where I was test running )

```
my_acc = ATM.new("Thomas", 700, 700, 1234)
my_acc.pin #also attempted using other methods no success
```

checking.rb source:

```
private

def checking_information
    puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
        >
        >Your current balance is: #{@checking_account}
        >Deposit funds '1'
        >Make a withdrawl '2'
        >Go back '3'
        >
    END
    input = gets.chomp
    case input.to_i
    when 1
        deposit
    when 2
        withdrawl
    when 3
        redirect
    else
        puts "Invalid option"
        checking_information
    end
end

def deposit
    puts "Enter amount to deposit:"
    amount = gets.chomp.to_i
    @checking_account += amount.to_f
    puts "Your new balance is #{@checking_account}"
    puts "Would you like make another deposit?"
    input = gets.chomp
    if input == /yes/i
        deposit
    else
        redirect
    end
end

def withdrawl
    puts "Your current balance is #{@checking_account}. Please enter amount to withdrawl:"
    input = gets.chomp.to_i
    @checking_account -= input.to_f
    puts "Your new balance is #{@checking_account}"
    puts "Would you like to make another withdrawl?"
    if input == /yes/i
        withdrawl
    else
        redirect
    end
end
```

Savings.rb, and transfer.rb aren't complete( haven't even started on them ) so there's not point in showing them.

loan.rb source:

```
private

class Loan 
    attr_accessor :credit
        def initialize( score )
            @score = 0
        end
    end

    def loan_info
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >Hello and welcome to the credit station
            >Please choose from the list below
            >Would you like to Apply for a loan '1'
            >Check credit score '2'
            >Go back '3'
            >
        END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            apply_credit
        when 2
            check_score
        else
            redirect
        end
    end

    def apply_credit
        if @score >= 640
            accepted
        else
            denied_loan
        end
    end

    def accepted
        loan = %w(100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000 2100 2200 2300 2400 2500 2600 2700 2800 2900 3000 3100 3200 3300 3400 3500 3600 3700 3800 3900 4000 4100 4200 4300 4400 4500 4600 4700 4800 4900 5000)
        loan_amount = loan.sample
        puts "You have been accepted for a #{loan_amount} loan which will be added to your bank account"
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >Which account would you like to add that to?
            >Checking Account '1'
            >Savings Account '2'
            >
        END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            @checking_account += loan_amount
            puts "#{loan_amount} has been added to your checking account, your new balance is #{@checking_account}"
            puts "Your card will now be returned for security purposes."
            exit_screen
        when 2
            @savings_account += loan_amount #Not completed yet..
            puts "#{loan_amount} has been added to your savings account, your new balance is #{@savings_account}"
            puts "Your card will now be returned for security purposes"
            exit_screen
        end
    end
```

redirect.rb and exit.rb source:

```
    def redirect
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
                >
                >Please choose from the list below
                >Main menu '1'
                >Checking inquiries  '2'
                >Savings account information '3'
                >Transfer funds '4'
                >Apply or view a loan '5'
                >Return card and exit system '6'
                >
            END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            menu
        when 2
            checking_information
        when 3
            savings_information
        when 4
            transfer_funds
        when 5
            loan_info
        when 6
            exit_screen
        else
            puts "Invalid input"
            redirect
        end
    end


----------

def exit_screen
    puts "Returning card.."
    puts "Thank you for choosing Bank of Bam, have a nice day!"
    exit
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

Well I was suggested to change the name and require main from the initialize file, so I did and BOOM same error, but this time it's got some stuff added to it:

```
`<top (required)>': private method `pin' 
called for #<ATM:0x00000016482f18> (NoMethodError)
```

Well isn't that just fancy.. Seems to be working except `pin` isn't a private method, excellent..( *sarcasm..* )

Comment: Is `main.rb` copied exactly from your version? If so, `pin()` appears to be defined outside the `ATM` class, because the class is closed with an `end` immediately after `initialize()`. Should `pin()` be included inside of the ATM class? (You may need to move an `end` down to the bottom of the class file, if so.)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that...

Comment: Did I answer your original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `initialize.rb` doesn't know what `ATM` is, because you haven't referenced it there via `require()`.

`initialize` implies startup behavior, but in this case it appears to be serving the purpose of a runner or executable, which most similar projects include, typically in a `bin` or now more commonly `exe` directory.

In that case you'd remove the reference to `initialize` from `main`, and require `main` in `initialize`.

I recommend looking at other command line gems for implementation ideas. Check out [this](http://robdodson.me/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/) article, particularly the [Executable](http://robdodson.me/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/#executable) section, for an explanation.

Comment: I used `initialize` because it's the first thing that popped into my head lol, so basically because I used `initialize` it's trying to initialize something through the file?

Comment: Nah, it isn't a magic naming thing. Check out the article (and other command line gems) to see exactly how to structure projects like this. You're close, you just need to arrange things slightly differently as suggested in my answer. `initialize` needs to require() main (where the ATM class is defined) to know what ATM is.

Comment: (Though there are times in Ruby Land where it *is* a magic naming thing.)

Comment: You also might consider implementing it as a gem via Bundler (which the article explains). This would provide structure by convention (with `lib` and `test` directories describing where stuff should go, for example), makes it manageable by RubyGems, etc.

Comment: I probably will, it's just not ready for that yet, this is what I get for doing a test run lol.

Answer (score 1):

You have `pin` and all other functions defined in global namespace, not inside `ATM` class:

```
class ATM
  attr_accessor :name, :checking_account, :savings_account, :pin_number, :transfer, :loan
    def initialize( name, checking_account, savings_account, pin_number )
        @name = name
        @checking_account = checking_account
        @savings_account = savings_account
        @pin_number = pin_number
    end
  end  ##### ⇐ THIS END JUST CLOSES ATM DECLARATION
```

Remove this `end` and enjoy.

Comment: Welcome; this kind of error is always hardest to catch.

Comment: If only I could accept more then one answer.. Or up vote about 60 times lol.

Answer (score 0):

When you require a file, its contents are executed, so when you require `initialize.rb` it runs the line of code that does `ATM.new(...)`

However the ATM class doesn't exist yet - it will only exist once ruby has finished executing `main.rb` (because that class is defined at the bottom  of that file), hence the error.

You need to either move where `initialize.rb` is required or reorganise your code so that all your classes are defined before you try to use them.